# Tailwind CSS + VueJS single file component and VS Code integration

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

How to properly configure Tailwind CSS and VS Code to at least disable errors about at-rule and empty tag error inside VueJS single file component (vue-cli)?

```
<template>
...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  body {
    // } expected
    @apply font-source pt-4;
  } // at-rule or selector expected

  h5,h4,h3,h2,h1 {
    // } expected
    @apply font-pt font-bold;
  } // at-rule or selector expected
</style>
```

Comment: disable the `es-lint` may it works

Comment: lol I don't want to disable es-lint lint.

Comment: then keep  `es-lint`

Answer (score 8):

I got it working with the help of this [guide](https://www.meidev.co/blog/visual-studio-code-css-linting-with-tailwind/)

TLDR

1. Install VS Code plugin stylelint (publisher name: stylelint)
2. Disable scss / css validation for the project. Hit F1 and search "settings json".

   > settings.json

```
"scss.validate": false
"css.validate": false
```

3. Add and configure stylelint plugin. Add the following file and contents to your project root.

   > stylelint.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'at-rule-no-unknown': [
            true,
            {
                ignoreAtRules: ['tailwind', 'apply', 'variants', 'responsive', 'screen']
            }
        ],
        'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
        'no-descending-specificity': null
    }
}
```

4. (optional) You "may" need to restart vs code to see the changes

Comment: Anyone in the future, if your validation settings are already false and you are still experiencing the problem, setting them to true then back to false worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add this to your VS Code workspace settings (.vscode/settings.json):

```json
{
  "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe remove lang="scss" or use the class directly in the template should work ?

Comment: OP is using SCSS, there's the issue. Removing it or changing to `lang="postcss"` breaks CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this error by changing my style's lang attribute to "postcss". Tailwind is essentially a PostCSS plugin.

`<style lang="postcss">`