# duplicate "Unknown at rule @apply css(unknownAtRules)" errors in Vue.js project

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project using `Vue.js` and `Tailwind CSS` and I get this error twice for the same line of code

```
Unknown at rule @apply css(unknownAtRules)
```

[image: VS Code Screenshote]

when using the follwing style

```
<style scoped>
     #home {
       @apply bg-accent-gradient;
     }
</style>
```

I found a soultion to add [PostCSS Language Support Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss) and the following to my vscode settings

```
"css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
```

I added it but it removed one error only not both.

Comment: Have a look at this [Tailwind CSS + VueJS single file component and VS Code integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56063082/tailwind-css-vuejs-single-file-component-and-vs-code-integration)

Comment: @Dhaifallah It worked, thanks! I'll wait for you to post this as an answer so that I choose it.

Comment: Glad it worked! I don't that would be necessary that would be duplicated answer, but thank you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Dhaifallah I cant mark a comment as a correct answer, please post an answer and i'll market as the correct one so that the question is closed

Comment: I post the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1- First Install VS Code plugin [stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint)

2- Then disable css and scss validation for the project. (ctrl+shift+p) and search "settings json".

```
"scss.validate": false
"css.validate": false
```

3- Create stylelint plugin config file in your project root `stylelint.config.js`

4- Add the following content to it in order to ignore at rules `apply, tailwind,etc`:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'at-rule-no-unknown': [
            true,
            {
                ignoreAtRules: ['tailwind', 'apply', 'variants', 'responsive', 'screen']
            }
        ],
        'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
        'no-descending-specificity': null
    }
}
```

Comment: someonne posted it inn the comments and it worked but now the warninings returned and I dont know why

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud Try to restart VS Code

Answer (score 12):

I had the same case, I went to vs code settings, searched for `Unknown At Rules` and select `ignore` there.

[image]

Comment: I've already done that and changed it to ignor fore LESS and SCSS too but it didn't work too

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `csstools.postcss` extension installed in the VScode before starting debugging the issue as other answers suggested.

Comment: Glad I read your answer first. That's all it was. VSCode didn't know what it was doing. MS should build this language support into VSCode

Answer (score 3):

Solution proposed in https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258#discussioncomment-1979394

Copy pasting here to follow StackOverflow Guidelines.

1. Create `.vscode` at the root of your project with the two files named

- `settings.json`
- `tailwind.json`

[image: Step 1]

2. Update the `settings.json` file

```json
{
  "css.customData": [".vscode/tailwind.json"]
}
```

3. Update the `tailwind.json` file

````json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@tailwind",
      "description": "Use the `@tailwind` directive to insert Tailwind's `base`, `components`, `utilities` and `screens` styles into your CSS.",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@apply",
      "description": "Use the `@apply` directive to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom CSS. This is useful when you find a common utility pattern in your HTML that you’d like to extract to a new component.",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@responsive",
      "description": "You can generate responsive variants of your own classes by wrapping their definitions in the `@responsive` directive:\n```css\n@responsive {\n  .alert {\n    background-color: #E53E3E;\n  }\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#responsive"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@screen",
      "description": "The `@screen` directive allows you to create media queries that reference your breakpoints by **name** instead of duplicating their values in your own CSS:\n```css\n@screen sm {\n  /* ... */\n}\n```\n…gets transformed into this:\n```css\n@media (min-width: 640px) {\n  /* ... */\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@variants",
      "description": "Generate `hover`, `focus`, `active` and other **variants** of your own utilities by wrapping their definitions in the `@variants` directive:\n```css\n@variants hover, focus {\n   .btn-brand {\n    background-color: #3182CE;\n  }\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#variants"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
````

Credits:

1. [Article by Duncan Leung](https://duncanleung.com/tailwind-css-unknown-at-rule/)
2. [@SeyyedKhandon](https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon)

Answer (score 2):

Adding lang="scss" worked for me:

```html
<style lang="scss">
/* my css with @apply */
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like you are using vscode.
For me i juste install `PostCSS Language Support` extension from vscode and it fix my error !